# Looking for electronics and sample code to drive commodity inkjet cartridge

Tags: arduino, msp430

I'd like to drive an inkjet cartridge, such as an [HP 94](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001IX1OLM) using a micro such as an Arduino or MSP 430.

Answer (score 1):

I recall that someone already did something like that... searching... .. .. .. oh yes: http://spritesmods.com/?art=inker

Hope that helps.